# Build child model after saving parent in jquery rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have a nested model and I would like to build the child model after the parent is created and would like to do this in the 'edit' view of the parent model. I am using jquery for the parent model.

#### parent controller

```
def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)
  if @student.save
    #### I would like to build the child model here
    #@student.student_grades.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render 'edit'}
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render 'new' }
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately the above code is not working. I also have the build line in the edit but it does not help since rendering goes straight to the view

**Update**
The problem was not the above code but code in the view. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please post the error you get and a stack trace if any.

Comment: From the logs, I can see it is redirecting to the home page, instead of rendering the 'edit'

Comment: Do you have a `before_action` or `before_filter` in the parent or `ApplicationController` that could redirect certain requests?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just c&p typo when copying it here, but you've used an uppercase 'S' on @Student in the second line, but are using a lowercase one on line 3